# JQuery Sort Divs Based on Content -Not Working-

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a multiple Divs that I want to sort using the JQuery sort function based on the product name attribute inside the product. However, when I click to run the function, all the divs will suddenly disappear, when I inspected to see the errors, there was no error displayed.

Kindly help me know what's the issue.

Here's my JQuery function and call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $divs = $("div.section-item");
        $("#asc").on("click", function(){
            var alphabetically = $divs.sort(function(a, b){
                return $(a).find(".name").text() > $(b).find("name").text();
            });
            $("#section-item").html(alphabetically);           
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the container with all the Divs:

```
<div id="block-section-item">
<div id="bdi-button">
    <button type="submit" id="asc" class="rec">Nom</button>
</div>
<div id="section-item">
    <?php
    include 'Include/__Class/Cls_Product.php';
    $product = new ClsProduct($bdd);
    $products = $product->DisplayAllProducts();

    foreach( $products as $row){
        echo'<div class="section-items">
                <span class="section-items-img">
                    <img src="Image/clio-full.jpg">
                </span>
                <span class="section-items-bottom">
                <span class="section-item-text">';
                echo '<h4 class="name">'.$row['Product_name'].'</h4>';
                echo '<h4 class="price">'.$row['Product_price'].'</h4>';
        echo'<span class="section-item-icon">
        <span class="voir-item"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id='.$row["Product_id"].'"></a></span>
        <span class="middle-item"></span>
        <span class="nakrih-item"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id='.$row["Product_id"].'"></a></span>
        </span>
        </span>';
        echo'</div>';
    }
    ?>                            
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="block-section-item">
    <div id="bdi-button">
        <button type="submit" id="asc" class="rec">Nom</button>
    </div>
    <div id="section-item">
        <div class="section-items">
            <span class="section-items-img">
                <img src="Chrysanthemum.gif">
            </span>
            <span class="section-items-bottom">
                <span class="section-item-text"><h4 class="name">Product_name2</h4><h4 class="price">22</h4><span class="section-item-icon">
                        <span class="voir-item"><a href="/test/index.php?id=2"></a></span>
                        <span class="middle-item"></span>
                        <span class="nakrih-item"><a href="/test/index.php?id=2"></a></span>
                    </span>
                </span></span></div><div class="section-items">
            <span class="section-items-img">
                <img src="Chrysanthemum.gif">
            </span>
            <span class="section-items-bottom">
                <span class="section-item-text"><h4 class="name">Product_name1</h4><h4 class="price">11</h4><span class="section-item-icon">
                        <span class="voir-item"><a href="/test/index.php?id=1"></a></span>
                        <span class="middle-item"></span>
                        <span class="nakrih-item"><a href="/test/index.php?id=1"></a></span>
                    </span>
                </span></span></div><div class="section-items">
            <span class="section-items-img">
                <img src="Chrysanthemum.gif">
            </span>
            <span class="section-items-bottom">
                <span class="section-item-text"><h4 class="name">Product_name3</h4><h4 class="price">33</h4><span class="section-item-icon">
                        <span class="voir-item"><a href="/test/index.php?id=3"></a></span>
                        <span class="middle-item"></span>
                        <span class="nakrih-item"><a href="/test/index.php?id=3"></a></span>
                    </span>
                </span></span></div>                            
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $divs = $(".section-items");
    $("#asc").on("click", function () {

        var alphabetically = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).find("[class='name']").text() > $(b).find("[class='name']").text();
        });
        $("#section-item").html(alphabetically);
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bs49L18k/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply, But can you tell me what are the changes you made in HTML file? because the JavaScript code is the same and it's not working. I have been checking the html file and i can't find a difference between mine and yours(in terms of class names and divs id)

This time it's not disappearing but the order is messy and not efficient

Comment: I actually did, I saw that you did couple of updates to your answer, however, the latest update I saw that it worked for you in  jsfiddle but in my code it didn't

Comment: Can you edit your question and put actual your code?

Comment: I see a big difference in your code, take a closer look